# OrientDB - Create edge to a vertex where user does not have _allow or _allowupdate permissions

Tags: security, graph, orientdb

I'm trying to create a change management system which allow different groups to update their own vertices and edges without being able to affect other groups vertices and edges but sometimes an edge, for example, needs to connect to a vertex created by another group and I can't find a way to make the permission do what I want.

Vertex A is created by webteam user

Vertex B is created by servicegroup user

Edge C needs to be created between Vertex A and Vertex B by servicegroup user but without allowing servicegroup user to change any other aspects of Vertex A (like it's name).

Any ideas?

Comment: To clarify I'm wanting to create a cross tenant edge.

Comment: Are you using server side functions? You could switch to a user who has permissions against those resources.